# Vaadin LoginOverlay add content below "Forgot password" (footer)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In the Login [demos](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples), each example has footer text stating "To close the login form submit non-empty username and password." I would like to replicate this but add more than text. I can call `LoginI18n#setAdditionalInformation(String)`, but it only supports plain text. For example, I would like to add another link similar to "Forgot password". Is this possible without creating a new Polymer element?

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login/blob/master/src/vaadin-login-form-wrapper.js#L92-L94), I'm afraid you need to create a new element:

```html
<div part="footer">
    <p>[[i18n.additionalInformation]]</p>
</div>
```

There is also feature request to make LoginOverlay more customizable in Vaadin's issue tracker.

https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/626

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I will just create a new composition.